# Multiple subprocess pipes python

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

This is my first time on here so please bear with me. I am working through some python code and having trouble with one block in particular so I will post my code from the test script I have been working on. I have even used print debugger statements to find out what's wrong and it appears the 3rd pipe is not getting stdin from the 2nd one even though the 2nd one is piping out the output. If I comment out output3 and use output2 the file gets created and populated but once I include output3 the file is completely empty. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

try:
  output = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'ax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  output2 = subprocess.Popen(['egrep', '/usr/'], stdin=output.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); output.stdout.close()
  output3 = subprocess.Popen(['egrep', '"sbin|lib"'], stdin=output2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); output2.stdout.close()
  with output3.stdout, open('some file name', 'ab') as file:
    for line in iter(output3.stdout.readline, b''):
      file.write(line)

except OSError as message:
  print "Display bad things {}!".format(message)
```

I had to hand jam this so sorry if I missed some typos!

Comment: This just looks like your regex is wrong. `'"sbin|lib"'` means the inner quotes are literal, not syntactic. That is to say, you're searching for either `"sbin` or `lib"`. Presumably what you really want is `'sbin|lib'`, without the extra quotes.

Comment: I am running commands on a Linux system so the quotes need to be there for the command ultimately to look like
ps ax |egrep /usr/ |egrep "sbin|lib"

Comment: The thing to understand is that in `egrep "sbin|lib"` passed to a shell, those double quotes are syntactic, not literal -- ie. they're serving the exact same purpose that the single quotes do in the Python, and aren't actually passed to `egrep`.

Comment: If I change the egrep to echo I get a text file that displays "sbin|lib"

Comment: With the double quotes in the output file? That makes my point.

Comment: `egrep "sbin|lib"` in bash turns into `execvp("egrep", char[][]{"egrep", "sbin|lib", NULL})`. That's the same thing that `subprocess.Popen(["egrep", "sbin|lib"])` does. By contrast, the code you're running in Python would be `egrep '"sbin|lib"'` in bash, and it would fail the same way if you ran it there.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want. The double quotes are necessary because I am asking egrep to locate either sbin or lib.

Comment: Please step back and reread what I'm telling you. The double quotes **are bash syntax, not passed to grep**. When you put them there in the Python code with `shell=False`, there *is* no shell to read and consume those quotes, so they *are* passed to grep, so you're running two very different commands.

Comment: Ok... I can kind of see now what you are saying. So how would I pass the literal egrep "sbin|lib" to a subprocess from python?

Comment: The way I told you in my very first comment. `['egrep', 'sbin|lib']`

Comment: Ok, I will have to test it when I have the availability. Thank you for the quick response and working through it with me!

Comment: BTW, is your intent to search for `/usr/sbin` or `/usr/lib`? If so, I'd suggest `['egrep', '/usr/(sbin|lib)']`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was able to run some tests this morning and your solution worked perfectly. I guess this goes to show I need to learn more about how this processes things under the hood.